# How to align dancers font chars within a TiKZ table

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts

I want to draw a `TikZ` table with two columns, the left column contains letters from A to Z and right column the corresponding `dancer`. The code I use is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin={1cm,1cm},hmargin={8mm,1cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}

\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{dancers}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{dancers}{m}{n}{<-> dancers}{}

\newcommand{\dancers}[1]{%
    \usefont{OT1}{dancers}{m}{n}\spaceskip=5pt
    #1}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style={draw, minimum size=7mm}]

\foreach \i [count=\ni from 0] in {A,B,...,Z}{
    \node[box] at (0,-\ni*7mm) {\i};
    \node[box] at (7mm,-\ni*7mm) {\dancers{\i}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and a detail of the result is:

[image]

As you can see the alignment is not very nice. How can I do it better? I would like to keep node size, but with corresponding `dancer` better centered inside it. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply a simple `\smash{\raisebox{-8pt}{}}` to the `\dancers{}`.

Without the `\smash`, you can lower each glyph as much as 12pt, before the vertical extent runs off the bottom of the glyph space and screws up the appearance of the chart.

It does seem unusual that the glyphs sit so high above the baseline (maybe they are jumping while dancing ;^)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[vmargin={1cm,1cm},hmargin={8mm,1cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{dancers}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{dancers}{m}{n}{<-> dancers}{}

\newcommand{\dancers}[1]{%
    \usefont{OT1}{dancers}{m}{n}\spaceskip=5pt
    #1}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style={draw, minimum size=7mm}]

\foreach \i [count=\ni from 0] in {A,B,...,Z}{
    \node[box] at (0,-\ni*7mm) {\i};
    \node[box] at (7mm,-\ni*7mm) {\smash{\raisebox{-8pt}{\dancers{\i}}}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]